# Return different code if variable is a string or not

Tags: php

I want to return a small block of code if the variable is a string, but if it is empty just return text "no image".

```
function link_img_preview( $atts, $content = null ) {
    if ( is_string( $content ) ) {
        $content = do_shortcode( str_replace( '###SPACE###', '', $content ) );
    }
    if ( is_string( $content ) == false ) {
        $content = 'no image';
    }
    require_once('OpenGraph.php');
    $graph = OpenGraph::fetch($content);
    $return = '<img class="link-image" src=';
    $return .= $graph->image;
    $return .= '>';
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Even an empty string is a string. Try strlen() or empty()

Comment: What happens when you run it currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after looking at your examples I realized that I had it all wrong in the first place. Here is what ended up working out for me. Thanks so much for the help!

```
function link_img_preview( $atts, $content = null ) {
require_once('OpenGraph.php');
    if ( is_string( $content ) ) {
        $content = do_shortcode( str_replace( '###SPACE###', '', $content ) );
}

$graph = OpenGraph::fetch($content);
if (!empty($graph->image)) {
$return = '<img class="link-image" src=';
$return .= $graph->image;
$return .= '>';
return $return;}
else{
return 'no image';
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

No need to overcomplicate things. The default value `$content = null` will evaluate as false, so if you don't provide the second argument you will get 'no image'. If you pass an empty string it will evaluate as false, so you will get 'no image'. If you pass something that is not a string to this function that appears to be expecting a string, it will throw an error, which seems to be a reasonable response.

```
if ($content) {
    $content = do_shortcode( str_replace( '###SPACE###', '', $content ) );
} else {
    $content = 'no image';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use  [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
if(empty($yourstring))
{
//your code
}
```

---

Code:

```
function link_img_preview( $atts, $content = null ) {
if (!empty($content)) {
$content = do_shortcode( str_replace( '###SPACE###', '', $content ) );
}else{
$content = 'no image';
}
require_once('OpenGraph.php');
$graph = OpenGraph::fetch($content);
$return = '<img class="link-image" src=';
$return .= $graph->image;
$return .= '>';
return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if $content is a string as you do it already, but check also if the string is empty. Something like `$a = "";` is a string too.

The code that does what you want is the following

```
function link_img_preview( $atts, $content = null ) {
  if ( !is_string( $content ) || empty ( $content) ) {
    $content = 'no image';
  } else {
    $content = do_shortcode( str_replace( '###SPACE###', '', $content ) );
  }
  require_once('OpenGraph.php');
  $graph = OpenGraph::fetch($content);
  $return = '<img class="link-image" src=';
  $return .= $graph->image;
  $return .= '>';
  return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, just a little cleaner, adding in double quotes around src val

```
$return = '<img class="link-image" src="';
$return .= $graph->image;
$return .= '" >';
```

(see the `"` in the last line)